# NEDB NodeJS find document and wait for the result

Tags: node.js, async-await, nedb

I am using NEDB for some local storage in an NodeJS Application. Therefore I do have an handlerscript "nedbhandler.js" which I do require in my main.js.

```
var NEDB = require('./nedbhandler.js');

async function test(){
    var value = await NEDB.getValue_byID(1);
    console.log(value)
}

test()
```

while in the *nedbhandler.js* is my query handled like this:

```
async function getValue_byID(id){
    db.config.findOne({ _id: id }, function (err, doc) {
        callback(doc);
    });
    function callback(doc) {
        console.log(doc)
        return doc;
    }
}

exports.getValue_byID = getValue_byID;
```

While the console from *nedbhandler.js* logs the expected value, the *main.js* still is undefined.

What would be the best practice to load all config querys before loading next function in the *main.js*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Hi, no unfortuanetly not. I copied and pasted the Chapter: ES2017+: Promises with async/await in my main.js but it still returns undefined.

Comment: Show us your updated code, please.

Comment: Your callback inside `getalueById` is happening in non-blocking mode(asynchronous). So when you are calling `getValueById` function with `await`. It will simply return undefined from function as it will not wait for `db.config.findOne` again non-blocking. Either you wait for `findone` to complete or try explicitly returning promise and resolve it when value is found.

Answer (score 1):

You want your `getValue_byID` function to return a promise

```
function getValue_byID(id){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.config.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, doc) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        });
    });
}
```

Note how I changed the `function` keyword to the more modern `=>` syntax.
It is also considered better practice to use `const` and `let` insteadof `var`

There is a wrapper module for nedb, called [NeDB-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nedb-promises). It does more or less what I have done here, so you can use async/await instead of callbacks.